# Monetary field to report in Odoo 11 without currency id

Tags: odoo, odoo-11

I try to print invoice lines in invoice report.
for

```xml
<span t-field="l.price_subtotal" t-options='{"widget": "monetary", "display_currency": o.currency_id}'/>
```

and for

```xml
<span t-field="l.price_subtotal" />
```

there is one output: "111.11 $"
But I need in lines price without sign.

If I make something like

```xml
<span t-esc="round(l.price_total, 2)"/>
```

it works, yes, but I lose currency formatting

1. Is there a way to tell monetary widget it shouldn't show currency?

   "display_currency": "False" doesn't work (
2. Where is monetary widget code? I can't find it in source files (

Comment: search for `class MonetaryConverter` :-)

Comment: Thank you
For me it's strange, that widgets are not in file with name witgets.py or something like that

Answer (score 5):

try this to remove currency sign from qweb.
with currency formatinng

```
<span t-esc="'{:,.2f}'.format(doc.price_subtotal)" >
```

OR
this will print without currency formating

```
<span t-field="doc.price_subtotal" t-field-options="{'widget':'False'}"/>
```

Comment: I've make some changes in MonetryConverter class:
added condition 
    if not options.get('no_currency_sign', False)

before pre/post formatting

Comment: that means everytime you have to pass currency sign to display it.

Comment: Both solutions eem to work in Oodo 16, but this leads to the problem that the formatting is wrong (1000 seperator, decimal points).
There seems to be a `hideSymbol` attribute, but I am unable to set that form a QWeb report:
https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/c00baa010e7981f16bf3047cee6aaee1fc0f7495/addons/web/static/src/views/fields/monetary/monetary_field.js#L60